# <Anonymous button> is not abstract

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jbutton, actionlistener

I have been working on this project basically all day, and, something isn't working. Basically what I am trying to do is create a button that will, when clicked, make a colored circle appear. However, no matter how I declare the `ActionListener`, it continually gives me the error that it is not abstract. My coding is below

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class button extends JPanel
{

    public button()
    {

        JButton change;
        Font font1 = new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 10);

        setBackground(Color.black);
        change = new JButton("Change Light");
        change.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event, Graphics page) 
            {
                page.setColor(Color.green);
                page.fillOval(20, 220, 60, 60);
            }
        });
        change.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        change.setFont(font1);

        add(change, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        change.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The error that I get when trying to compile this is:

> "error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>  `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` in `ActionListener`
>   `change.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){"`

I always end up with this result when I follow examples online, so, I know that I must be really close- but I have been doing this for hours and can use some help. Does anyone know what my error is?

A little note is that if I try to make anything abstract, I get a million MORE errors same as if I say the class as a whole `implements ActionListener`

Comment: Any time you're overriding a method, annotate it with `@Override` to spot mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionListener` does not define a method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event, Graphics page)`

See the [`ActionListener` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), [How to Write an `ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

**For example**

```
change.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {...
```

**Updated**

Pass the reference of `Graphics` which need to the constructor of `Button`.  Because of the way that anonymous classes reference variables, you will either need to make the parameter `final` and reference it directly, or, create an instance variable to maintain a reference to the value you pass, for example...

```
public class Button extends JPanel
{
    private Graphics page;
    public Button(Graphics aPage)
    {

        page = aPage;
        JButton change;
        Font font1 = new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 10);


        setBackground(Color.black);
        change = new JButton("Change Light");
        change.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
            {
                page.setColor(Color.green);
                page.fillOval(20, 220, 60, 60);
```

Have now looked more deeply into your code, I hope you are not passing the `Graphics` context of a life component, as this will snap around and bite you

Comment: See, I read the java docs, and 1. they for some reason just weren't clicking to me, and two, when I tried it akin to the docs I got the same result. I refrenced http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/278-how-add-actionlistener-jbutton-swing.html for the attempt I showed here. This is only one of four or five ways I tried

Comment: Alright, so, basically its because I can't have graphics in the action listener, right? then where should I put it? if I put it in the button class then I get an error saying that the ones in the actionlistener need to be declared Final, which, creates more errors. The point of this button is to make it draw a circle to the canvas of the class it's a part of

Comment: Given the fact that I can't even see where `page` is actually defined only leaves me with guess work.  I would suggest that you pass a reference of `page` to the `button` class via it's constructor.  I would then maintain a reference to this via an instance field in `button` so you can access it when you need to...

Comment: Also, Java class names should start with an uppercase character (`Button`), but beware, there is already a class called `Button` in `java.awt` which might cause confusion ;)

Comment: page is (was) originally in the action listener, as seen in your comment. Its referring to the creation of Graphics. by taking it out of the action listener it gets rid of the abstract issue but creates the issue that nothing can refrence it

Comment: Oh I see, but how is `page` getting to the `button` class?

Comment: see thats the thing I was wondering about. I thought you could just declare it inside the action listener but I was wrong. however, button is an object, so, I can't declare one in the parameters of button because then it expects that I'm passing in a page, which I'm not, because the page belongs to a separate class which draws an image. the point of the button is that its supposed to change the image when you press it.

Comment: So back to my original comment, pass the reference of `page` to the `constructor` of `button`...

Comment: even when I do that, it says that page needs to be declared final. I have edited it to pass in a page to the constructor, but, it hasnt fixed anything

Comment: okay, the awesome news is that that made the object class actually compile! the UNawesome thing is that it did horrible things when I implemented this- because in order to load it into the main class, I had to pass it some sort of Graphics, so I passed it a Grapihcs variable set to null. it compiles, but, when I push the button, I get a million errors

Comment: Yup.  Instead, try passing the some kind of "Drawable" class instead (your going to have to create it), that has methods that allow you execute commands against it (ie `drawOval`) which it can the paint itself...

Comment: well basically, I have given up. http://pastebin.com/5G2xM8s1, http://pastebin.com/nMMciF6q, http://pastebin.com/3e51XP8m are what they looked like before i tried to do action listeners- if anyone wants to see for educational purposes. My conclusion is that I screwed something, and since I have been doing this for 13 hours- I give up. Thanks though, for all the help. you know what you're talking about and I appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer which draws a circle based on the state of a `JToggleButton`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGUI {
    JToggleButton draw = new JToggleButton("Draw");

    public TestGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        final CirclePanel panel = new CirclePanel();
        draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                panel.setDraw(draw.isSelected());
                frame.repaint();

            }

        });
        frame.add(draw, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private class CirclePanel extends JPanel {

        private boolean draw = false;

        public void setDraw(boolean toDraw) {
            draw = toDraw;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (draw) {
                g.drawOval(200, 200, 50, 50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```